# Why is this code not compliant with MISRA-C 2012 Rule 11.3

Tags: c, pointers, misra

I'm having a very hard time understanding why the following code gives me two errors regarding rule 11.3

```
#define NUM_TASKS 3

typedef struct
{
    void (*TaskFunc)(void);
    uint32_t     Periodicity;
    uint32_t     StartOffset;
} TaskConfig_t;

typedef enum
{
    IDLE,
    RUNNING
} TaskStatus_t;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t ExecTime;
    uint32_t MinExecTime;
    uint32_t MaxExecTime;
} TaskMetrics_t;

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t TimeToRun;
    uint8_t OverrunCnt;
    TaskStatus_t Status;  
    TaskMetrics_t Metrics;      
} TaskParam_t;

typedef struct
{
  uint32_t *CpuUtilizationPercent;
  uint32_t *Counter;
  TaskParam_t *Params;
  TaskConfig_t *Tasks;
  uint8_t NumTasks;
} PPTS_Config_t;

static uint32_t PPTS_CpuUtilizationPercent;
static uint32_t PPTS_Counter;

static TaskParam_t TaskParams[NUM_TASKS];

static TaskConfig_t TaskConfig[NUM_TASKS];

const PPTS_Config_t CnfPPTS =
{
  &PPTS_CpuUtilizationPercent,
  &PPTS_Counter,
  TaskParams,  /* MISRA-C rule 11.3 violation */
  TaskConfig,   /* MISRA-C rule 11.3 violation */
  NUM_TASKS
};
```

And in both cases the error is: A cast shall not be performed between a pointer to object type and a pointer to a different object type

The thing here is that both **TaskParams** and **TaskConfig** are pointers of the same type that are the struct elements **Params** and **Tasks** respectively. I don't understand why I can't assign ***TaskParams*** to ****Params*** if they have the exact same type. Am I missign something?

Thank you very much for helping and I hope this could be explained because I'm really frustrated.

**EDIT:** I've included all the related data types if that helps somehow.

Regards.

Comment: As stated, arrays are not pointers. Does the following work: `&TaskParams[0]`? @Olaf, not sure if you mean TaskParams is not writable, or its contents are not writable.

Comment: @Kupiakos: Sorry, I was not clear about that. The name/address of the array is not writeable, of course the array contents _is_.

Comment: &TaskParams[0] does not work either.

Comment: Please quote the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: This is the exact quote: MISRA-C rule 11.3 violation: [R] A cast shall not be performed between a pointer to object type and a pointer to a different object type

Comment: Your compliance checker might be buggy. Its quality-of-implementation is nonexistent. What the... You are saying I cannot convert between different pointer types, and you are not naming these types? Well, you must be working for the automotive industry!

Comment: Try designated initializers. And check for updates/erratas of your checker tool (would not be the first tool reporting false positives).

Comment: I don't know, Wikipedia lists a bunch, try those that have free evaluation. I have no idea if any of them is good, I don't believe in MISRA-C and fortunately I'm not forced to use it.

Comment: @n.m.: Yes it's for the automotive industry and yes it's being enforced here. Also the checker is for a tool made by Altium so I think has tons of errors. Is the TriCore Eclipse IDE v5.0r2

Comment: There is no cast being performed anywhere in the posted code. I believe 11.3 cannot possibly apply to a situation without a type conversion operator (commonly known as "cast") being explicitly present.

Comment: Does the precise snippet above generate the error, or did you provide a simplified view of code that has not actually been run through the tool? Can you actually provide a minimal compilable example that also generates the error?

Comment: @jxh: That is the exact same code snippet, I didn't even changed the names.

Comment: can you show us the typedefs for TaskParam_t and TaskConfig_t? Though it doesn't matter, this is not a violation.

Comment: @Veriloud: I've included all the data types related. Maybe MISRA rule checking is like error checking with klockwork, I don't know.

Comment: @m4l490n, yep, nothing strange on the updated example, this is not a violation, n.m. is correct (though wrong for not believing in MISRA ;-)

Comment: @m4l490n: As you had a similar problem some days ago, I'd strongly recommend to trust moreyour wits than the tool. On the next error, kick the vendor in the bu** first. No harm if **that** proves wrong lateron.

Comment: one cast that i do see is from int32_t(NUM_TASKS is not unsigned) to uint8_t(uint8_t NumTasks). dunno how your misra tool didnt catch that.

Answer (score 4):

MISRA-C 2004 6.10.7 implies that a cast is an **explicit** type conversion, and gives a bunch of examples in the form of `(type)value`. This is consistent with the common definition of the term. I believe we can use this definition for the purpose of discussing MISRA-C compliance.

There is no cast being performed anywhere in the posted code. 11.3 says something about casting between different types. I believe 11.3 cannot possibly apply to a situation without a cast, as defined above, being present, no matter what the types involved are.

I conclude that the checker is at fault, and a gross one at that.

Comment: n.m. is correct, there is no reason for a 11.3 violation here at all that I, nor my tool, can find.

Comment: Also, yes, cast is defined in "MISRA-C:2012 C.1.2 Explicit Conversions" as with convention.